# Can we send the HttpResponse of django `render()` in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-views

What my use case is I need whole render() data into a dictionary which will be having other key values too and finally I can return it as a normal Response.

Let suppose my code is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
        'foo': 'bar',
    }, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

Now what we are doing here is: render is basically returning a HttpResponse which we are returning.

What I need is:

Save the return response in a variable

```
x = render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
            'foo': 'bar',
        }, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

Then can we save it in a dictionary to return as a Response? Like this

```
y = {}
y = {name: 'testing', render_response: x}
return y
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you want here, but I think you are looking for [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string).

Comment: What do you mean "whole render() data" ???

Answer (score 1):

You cant return a plain dictionary from a view, it should return a [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view) object. You can return a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) from your view. Like @Daniel mentioned in comments, use [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) to get response in string format.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse


def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    response = render_to_string('myapp/index.html', {'foo': 'bar'}, request=request)
    context = {'name': 'testing', 'render_response': response}
    return JsonResponse(context)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: yes, you can. Your code, which I am rewriting here, is absolutely valid:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    x = render(
        request,
        'myapp/index.html',
        {'foo': 'bar'},
        content_type='application/xhtml+xml'
    )
    y = {name: 'testing', render_response: x}
    return y
```

That said, you have to keep in mind that `my_view` is no longer a valid Django view. It is just a function that takes a `request` object and returns a dictionary (with an `HttpResponse` as one of its values).

For that reason, you will not be able to use this function in places where view functions are expected, such as in `urlpatterns`. A possible use of this function would be within a valid view function (which retrieves the returned `HttpResponse` object and returns it directly).